# How do you get the top 10 items in an array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to get the top 10 items in an array, I have an array that has several hundred items and I would like to get the top 10 items (most duplicated items) from the array using PHP, any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @SpacedMonkey Haha, thanks!  I'm not sure why I didn't go straight their! :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$inputArray = array('orange','banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'pear', 'orange', 'apples','orange', 'grape', 'apple');

$countedArray = array_count_values($inputArray);
arsort($countedArray);

$topTen = array_slice($countedArray, 0, 10);
```

The above will return the array in order of the items with the most occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Try using php's [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the number of occurrences of each value in the array, in conjunction with [`arsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort the array by the highest frequency values. Then you can take the top 10 most frequent values of the array with [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$dataArr = array('test', 4, 15.2, ...); // Input array with all data
$frequencies = array_count_values($dataArr);
arsort($frequencies); // Sort by the most frequent matches first.
$tenFrequencies = array_slice($frequencies, 0, 10, TRUE); // Only get the top 10 most frequent
$topTenValues = array_keys($tenFrequencies);
```

**Note:** We need to use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the final values because `array_count_values()` "returns an array using the values of the input array as keys and their frequency in input as values."